# Selenium connection to the local host failed

Tags: selenium

I am getting the following error when I try to run the JUnit test in Java

```
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:' 
    org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 
    localhost:19114 
    [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection 
    refused: connect'
    Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'  
    os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
    Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at
```

Comment: A problem might occur due to a version of your firefox browser. 
Please do update it and then check.

Comment: I am still having the same issue after updating the browser. I had to downgrade the browser version and the Selenium server version as well to make it work. Thanks

Comment: No mention1 you can upvote my comment :D